# how to check whether excel file is of 2007 or 2010 office

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

i am using following code to differentiate excel file of 2003 and 2007 office.

```
if (Extension == ".xls" || Extension == ".xlsx")
 {
 }
```

but now i also need to identify 2010 excel file. please suggest some solution.

Comment: Are you using excel object model to generate the file? If now, how are you generating it?

Comment: excel file will be uploaded by user and it will be available in solution only.

Comment: Note that Excel 2010 files don't differ significantly from 2007 files. Nonetheless, I posted an explanation of how to differentiate them based on the version number contained inside.

Comment: the file extension (xls or xlsx) defines the format of the file, NOT which version created it - Excel 2007 can create  xls files as well as xlsx files etc

Answer (score 8):

You're probably aware that .xlsx files (like all Office Open XML files) are actually .zip files that contain a set of inner files that describe the content.  So here's where you go to find the version number of the program that saved the file:

Rename the .xlsx extension to .zip (when you're doing this programatically, you can skip that step, but it's helpful for demonstration). Open up the zipped structure contained in the file.

You'll find a `docProps` directory inside, which contains a file called `app.xml` (open it). You'll find something that looks like this:

```
<Properties>
  <Application>Microsoft Excel</Application>
  <DocSecurity>0</DocSecurity>
  <ScaleCrop>false</ScaleCrop>
  <HeadingPairs>
    <vt:vector size="2" baseType="variant">
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:lpstr>Worksheets</vt:lpstr>
      </vt:variant>
      <vt:variant>
        <vt:i4>3</vt:i4>
      </vt:variant>
    </vt:vector>
  </HeadingPairs>
  <TitlesOfParts>
    <vt:vector size="3" baseType="lpstr">
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet1</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet2</vt:lpstr>
      <vt:lpstr>Sheet3</vt:lpstr>
    </vt:vector>
  </TitlesOfParts>
  <LinksUpToDate>false</LinksUpToDate>
  <SharedDoc>false</SharedDoc>
  <HyperlinksChanged>false</HyperlinksChanged>
  <AppVersion>14.0300</AppVersion>
</Properties>
```

See the `<Application>` tag? That tells you that it was saved in Excel (as opposed to, say Open Office). See the `<AppVersion>` tag? That one has the version number you're looking for. Excel 2007 is version 12, and Excel 2010 is 14 (because using version number 13 would have jinxed the whole operation). Excel 2013 is expected to be version 15.

Comment: Note that the `docProps` section is not a required part of the xlsx specification. Documents created using programs other than Excel may not have it. If you create an xlsx file using Google Drive, for example, it won't have any of this information.